# When using IdentityServer, what is the best practice of saving/accessing external claims from Google?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

My IdentityServer application is configured to use Google login. I am using OIDC. This question is about external claims.

At login time, my application has access to all of the claims Google sends back from the auth request. I can access them in my custom implementation of UserServiceBase in the method AuthenticateExternalAsync (via the context). I can even add them to the AuthenticateResult object so when GetProfileDataAsync gets executed after the user has accepted the consent, I can access them via the ProfileDataRequestContext.Subject.Claims list. But this is the last point they will be in memory.

If I do not save these claims in a database, how can I access them once the login process is over? I want to keep my id_token simple so I do not put claims (other than sub) in the token. So I need to call the /userinfo end point to get the claims, but by this point they are no longer in memory.

What is the cleanest way of getting these claims back? To be clear, I want to get the claims from Google when the user calls /userinfo and translate them to the claims naming convention of my application. (I do not want to store them in the id_token at login time if possible... as per OIDC spec)

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760676/owin-access-external-claims-in-subsequent-requests) question is similar to mine, but that does not address how to do it using IdentityServer3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need some persistence mechanism for the claims from the external provider. You should already have this, as the subject claim that you are issuing from IdentityServer should be unique to your token service (and not the unique id google gives you).

Comment: Is it best to store the claims once at authentication time OR should you save the access_token that Google issues at authentication time and make the HTTP requests to the Google Plus API whenever IdentityServer requests the claims?